# how to convert a string that contain array element into JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays

I've been experiencing some problems for quite some time trying to load a string that contains an array into a JSONArray. 
i get the following string from a web-service which contains the movies array:
{"total":3,"movies":[],"links":{......}"}

i'm looking to convert this array into a JASONArray and show it using a list view.
i'm using the following code and it not working....

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result);

        if (result==null || result.length()==0){
            // no result:
            return;
        }

        //clear the list
        moviesList.clear();

        try {
            //turn the result into a JSON object
            Log.d(TAG, "create responseObject: "); 

            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);

            Log.d(TAG, responseObject.toString());

            // get the JSON array named "movies"
            JSONArray resultsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("movies");             
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONArray lenght: " + resultsArray.length());

            // Iterate over the JSON array: 
            for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                // the JSON object in position i 
                JSONObject movieObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "movieObject (from array) : " + movieObject.toString());

                // get the primitive values in the object
                String title = movieObject.getString("title");
                String details = movieObject.getString("synopsis");

                //put into the list:
                Movie movie = new Movie(title, details, null,null);
                //public Movie(String title, String details, String urlnet, String urldevice) {
                moviesList.add(movie);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //refresh listView:
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

I was hoping a post here would help me solve the problem.

Comment: "it not working" ... What is not working ? Do you get an error ? If so, post it as well. Thank you.

Comment: can you post more info about your Json object? `{"total":3,"movies":[],"links":{......}"}` not enough, at least show how `movies` look like. Thanks

Comment: i dont get a JSONArray out of movies from the input string. no error. tx lora

Comment: sorry, i'm a rookie in android and here so i can't post more than 2 links ... i've printed to the log the result string i have (Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result);) and the log looks like that:
{"total":3,"movies":[],"links":{"self":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=aaaa&page_limit=5&page=5","prev":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=aaaa&page_limit=5&page=4"},"link_template":"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q={search-term}&page_limit={results-per-page}&page={page-number}"}

Comment: your `movies` is empty

Comment: you are so right !!!!! i've tried to search for a "real movie and not "aaa" and got answers and the list is filled... tx !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

to this:

```
JSONObject responseObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(result);
```

and then you can get your `JSONArray`.

Comment: tx, but what is: JSONValue ?
i get the following error: 
JSONValue cannot be resolved

Comment: For working with JSON I use this: [link](https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/)
and this library has that field.

Comment: as a rookie i don't know how to do it.... 
i've downloaded the library and saved it in my project under the libs, how to include it ?
i also tried putting it under com.example.mymovies1 (the package) and : 
import com.example.mymovies1.*;
in both cases i still get the error.
i'll appropriate if u can explain it for a rookie ... (:

Comment: Go to the Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> add external JAR.